# Code background from Visual Studio

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2013, microsoft-office-2016, microsoft-word-2016

I want to paste some code in my Word document from Visual Studio 2016, but the text has a white background. For readability I want to keep the formatting and the colors of the code.

When I try to remove the shading in the Borders and Shading dialog, it says there is no shading (!). How the remove the white background?

The Reveal Formatting says: SHADING Pattern: Clear (White)

*Note: I inserted the code text as an object*

[image]

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by `'I inserted the code text as an object'`? That implies you are using an OLE object but you mention earlier in the post that you are pasting the text.

Comment: Yes I am using a OLE object where I paste the code

Comment: What is the type of the OLE object where you are pasting the code and what is the type of the main hosting document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I select one word, I can modify the styling with Borders and Shading (set background to transparent). When I select all the text with Ctrl+A, it's not working.

I found the solution (hard way) by writing a macro:

```
Sub Test()

For i = 1 To Selection.Words.Count
      Selection.Words(i).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorAutomatic
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

- Change the highlight colour (Ribbon: `Home` Tab / grouped under `Font` / `Text Highlight Colour`) from white to anything else or `No Colour`.
- For more information, select part of the text and use `Reveal Formatting` (`CTRL + ALT + SHIFT + S` to show the styles pane \ click middle button `Style Inspector` \ click button `Reveal Formatting`).

Comment: No that is not the problem

Comment: @TimHovius Are you sure it isn't this solution...? I replicated your issue and it just seems to be highlighted in white: http://i.imgur.com/zy3UCNI.gifv

Comment: @TimHovius I added something that could help you, although I'm sure it's about the highlight colour because there is no other colour options than what was mentioned here :)

Answer (score 0):

I have VS open. I opened Word, changed the background to a horrible green and then  I just copied at pasted and it works and keeps formatting

[image]

1. Please make sure you don't have any highligting (as pointed out by [Sanny](https://superuser.com/a/1087623/146314))
2. Make sure you don't have a search as that can add highlighting
3. Please make sure text is normal (under styles)
4. Select all content, and right click and choose font. Then choose Text Effects (at bottom) and review all options in left menu.
5. It's possible it's HTML. To test, copy the information and paste into Notepad. Then copy from Notepad back to Word to see if it changes.

Comment: Yes that is not the problem, but I want to remove the white background from the pasted text. Change your page background color for example and you will see it :)

Comment: @TimHovius, updated

Comment: But did you try copy and pasting instead of inserting objects?

Comment: Yes, but the same problem

Comment: Sorry to ask, but can you try with a new Word document? Open doc, make the background colour from the Page Layout - Page Background tab and then paste.

Comment: I have tried it. Temporary solution: Paste text in Wordpad, set text highlight color to transparent and copy back to Word