# Very light blue behind my text in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

I got a slight hint of blue behind some part of my text, indicated by the blue arrow in the following image (the red arrow text is fine):

[image]

I have no idea why, I tried changing the highlighting but it didn't work.

Comment: See if this helps http://superuser.com/questions/1087613/code-background-from-visual-studio

Comment: This question lacks details for any specific answer. All we can do is make assumptions. Tell us more about the document and text. How is the text placed there, typed or pasted? Are these text boxes or form fields you are dealing with? Is this in a table or regular paragraph?

Comment: Are you wearing glasses (chromatic aberration)?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out! All I did was copy and pasted it below on the same document. It will paste with the light blue still but then a little box with a clipboard and paper pops up at the end of the paragraph so click on it and select “Match Destination Formatting” and it should go back to normal. Then just delete the light blue paragraphs and put in the cleaned up paragraphs. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have attempted to copy and paste a piece of text which has been formatted. Just paste your desired text into a document as plain text using Ctrl + Shift + V which will remove any previous formatting and make it nice and clean.

Answer (score 0):

It might be text shading and can be updated. Check the Borders and Shading dialog (click the Borders dropdown in the Paragraph group of the Home tab of the ribbon, and select the last option: Borders and Shading; then activate the Shading tab)